# Get img url from uploads folder in cakephp

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I'm have images in webroot/uploads folder, Can I use this files in img tag? And what link in href i must use

```
<img src="/webroot/uploads/1.jpg"> is not work =(
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in php file:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>uploads/1.jpg"/>
```

**OR**

directly without php (if your site is hosted at the **root of the domain**)

```
<img src="/uploads/1.jpg">
```